# Функции высокого и низкого уровня в C/C++

Tags: c++, c, терминология

Мне нужно записать данные в файл .txt используя функции высокого уровня,а считать данные из файла используя функции низкого уровня на С и С++. Что это за функции такие и в чем их отличие?

Comment: ofstream для вывода в файл и, возможно, [ReadFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-readfile) для инпута, если Вы работаете с Windows

Comment: Это такие формулировки в заданиях для учащихся? Или вы своими словами изложили?

Comment: @NewView это  задание по ООП

Comment: @xxclojure , а как быть с простым си? Ведь он ofsteam не поддерживает

Comment: Забавно, кто автор задания :) низкий уровень - условно, это например код на асемблере, или прямо в машинных кодах :) так же вероятно к этому можно отнести syscall из ядра. Высокий уровень - все остальное :) тут скорее нужно знать нижний порог знаний преподавателя, с чем он сталкивался, и что для него является наименьшим уровнем :)

Comment: @NewView, извините, но Вам не кажется, что здесь имеет место быть дословный перевод вполне стандартной терминологии? На мой взгляд, Вы напрасно усомнились в знаниях преподавателя.

Answer (score 0):

Функции ввода-вывода высокого уровня - это [функции стандартной библиотеки для работы с файлами](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c), оперирующие абстрактными потоками. Например: fopen, fread. Они одинаковы во всех реализациях С/С++, именно они используются чаще всего.

Функции ввода-вывода низкого уровня - это специфичные для конкретной реализации функции, оперирующие дескрипторами объектов операционной системы. Они выполняют только непосредственный ввод/вывод байт, без буферизации или преобразования данных в другой формат. Они могут использоваться, когда на это есть особые причины, например, связанные с производительностью или необходимостью доступа к каким-то возможностям ОС, недоступным при использовании потоков. Примеры:

[Low-Level I/O в Microsoft CRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/low-level-i-o?view=vs-2019)

[Low-Level Input/Output в glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-I_002fO.html#Low_002dLevel-I_002fO)